# Does WebCrypto also mandate the crypto algorithms be implemented in Javascript?

Tags: cryptography, web-browser

I am trying to understand what WebCrypto means. From what I understand it is -

A Javascript Crypto API spec that all browsers must (hopefully) support. Am I correct?

If so are the crypto algorithms implementated in Javascript? Or the algorithms from the underlying platform simply exported through the WebCrypto API? What do browsers do?

Answer (score 2):

> A Javascript Crypto API spec that all browsers must (hopefully) support. Am i correct?

Hopefully all browsers should support it, though currently it's still work in progress.

The specification does not mandate that the API be implemented in JavaScript. Developers are free to choose their [underlying implementation](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#concepts-underlying-implementation), it could be JS, or a built in part of the browser, a plugin, a hardware module, etc. [This post](http://poulpita.com/2013/07/31/first-web-crypto-implementations-expecting-your-imagination-to-play-with/) introduces some of the currently available implementations and the technologies used to develop them.